# google application script assign function when cell is clicked

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, google-sheets-macros

[image: Spreadsheet]

I am attempting to make many buttons on a Google Sheets spreadsheet that will record my cryptocurrency trades in a format that is specific to my trade strategy. The details of that strategy are not important for this issue. I only want to run a relative script whenever the (Trade!) button is clicked. I want to copy a lot of them, so it wouldn't make sense to make an individual macro for each buy/sell range. Two possible directions for a solution are clear to me, but I can't find information on either.

Possible solution 1: Assign a macro to a cell when it is selected and put the button inside the cell. I can do this with VBA, but cannot find instructions on how to do this for Google Sheets Script.

Possible solution 2: Have the function select the relative cell beneath the button that was clicked. Targeting cells relative to other cells is easy enough, but I can't seem to find a command for targeting a cell relative to an image. Again, this is doable in Excel with VBA, but I can't find the same function for Google Sheets Script.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use checkboxes and this onEdit() code to call whatever function you wish.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('Entry');
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='Trades' && e.range.columnStart==7 && e.range.rowStart>2 && e.value=="TRUE") {
    e.range.setValue('FALSE');
    e.source.toast('You clicked cell ' + e.range.getA1Notation());
    //call whatever function you wish to call
  }
}
```

Animation:

[image]